# HTML input placeholder, first letter CSS changes is not working with updated browser

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm applying css for first letter in input placeholder

I have tried to add ::first-letter pseudo class to get the same. But my browser is updated one, so changes are not reflecting in updated browser here.

CSS:

```
.placeholder-ele-Casing{
  ::placeholder{
    text-transform: lowercase !important;
    &::first-letter{
      text-transform: uppercase !important;
    }
  }
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    text-transform: lowercase !important;
    &::first-letter{
      text-transform: uppercase !important;
    }
  }
}

<input type='text' class='placeholder-ele-Casing' placeholder='Mobile Number' />
```

Here I have used the placeholder to get the proper sentence casing.

Like this 'Mobile number'.

But i have found only lowercase transform of the text.. not the first-letter element...

Answer (score 2):

Your compiled CSS will be like

```
.placeholder-ele-Casing::placeholder {
  text-transform: lowercase !important;
} 

.placeholder-ele-Casing::placeholder::first-letter { /*will not work*/
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

> `::placeholder` and `::first-letter` both are pseudo elements, so you
>   can't append the pseudo element after pseudo element while
>   Pseudo-classes are allowed anywhere.

So **to make the first letter capital**, you can just use

```
.placeholder-ele-Casing::placeholder {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

which will convert "mobile number" to "Mobile Number", but *will not work for the text "mOBile number", to achieve this you need javascript*.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If it will not work as you said... So, how can I apply first letter css on placeholder input. Waiting for reply.

Comment: As I mentioned in the last line of my answer, JavaScript is needed to achieve this. If you want I will add JavaScript code for the same.

Comment: Yes, if possible try to search placeholder and first letter pseudo class of css. Highly recommended to read. And this first-letter pseudo class is not working for updated browsers.

Comment: I know about both of the pseudo elements, and first-letter was pseudo class previously now it is pseudo element.

Comment: But currently it is deprecated for updated chrome browser. 
`::first-letter` pseudo class element for `::placeholder` 

Try to understand, all I am talking about input placeholder text, and applying `::first-letter` pseudo class into in it. 

But it is not working only because it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS CSS CODE

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
      text-transform: initial;

}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    text-transform: initial;

}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    text-transform: initial;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    text-transform: initial;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @MohcinBN here my use case is different... And first-letter pseudo class is get in deprecated in new browser. Let me know the way if found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder initial styles

```
.placeholder-ele-Casing {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

&::placeholder{
  text-transform: initial;
}
```